# Can't tell who I voted for with the new button styling

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, election

When we had the old and boring button styles, voting for someone in an election would put a border around the vote used.

That doesn't happen anymore with the hawt new button style.

I know the candidates I voted for are listed in the right sidebar, but even with that and even though we show a notification when the vote is cast, it's pretty weird not to have the button respond in any way. At first I wasn't even sure my first vote got registered.

Can we have the border back?

P.S. The "2nd choice" button is slightly wider than the other two. **twitch**

[image]

Comment: I noticed the 2nd choice button independently; at least I get to use the image somewhere. fixitfixitfixitfixit

Comment: I agree: *"It still bothers me that the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd choice buttons are all different widths..."* ([source](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8161773#8161773))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently this got fixed at some point:

[image]